# Firefox tries to parse XML even with Content-Type: text/plain

Tags: java, html, xml, firefox

I'm using the Spark java framework to serve pages.

```
response.type("text/plain;charset=utf-8");
return "hello";
```

Even with that, Firefox tells me:

XML Parsing Error: syntax error

Any ideas on how to fix this? Firefox appears to be parsing as XML even though I explicitly tell it to use `text/plain`.

Comment: Not familiar with Spark, but does only `"text/plain"` (without the charset) work?

Comment: No, even if I just use `text/plain` without the `charset`, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. Apparently Spark version 1.0 doesn't work with Firefox. Updating Spark to 1.1 fixed my Firefox issues. I did, however, have to leave in the `response.type()` call.